individualize multi projects in angular
I have an angular app that contains multiple projects
I create project as so:
ng generate application my-inner-project
The only problem I have now is that all my dependencies ( package.json ), jest setups, angular.json... are in the root app and my inner projects cannot be ran standalone.
Do you know a way to individualize those projects so they can run alone and be publishable?
